# select box reset Mozilla firebox not working

Tags: css

select box reset working in chrome browser  **-webkit-appearance:none**. But does not work firebox(*version* **33.0**) **-moz-appearance: none**.

Any one suggestion me...

```
<select class="form-class">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
<style>
select {
border: 1px solid #aeb0b6;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 0.2em 22px 0.2em 0.3em;
  background: #fff url(images/arrow-down-bk-blue.png) center right no-repeat;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: It's working fine for me on firefox v43 (same as chrome) - https://jsfiddle.net/bonq0vk8/

Comment: I know, but this version 33.0 not working.